# Where are logs for witadmin actions in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

When running the witadmin command from the Visual Studio 2010 Command Line, where is this action logged in TFS 2010?  An example command would be:

C:>witadmin exportwitd -collection:http://server:8080/tfs/projectcollection -p:TeamProject -n:Bug -f:c:\Bug.xml

Comment: By "logged" do you mean you want to see who has done this action and when?

Comment: Yep, an audit log.  Log file.  Event logger.  Something.  Trying to find out who changed the Work Item Template and when they did it...

Comment: I think you're going to find the answer is "there is no log."  I've starred the question, because I would love to know the answer as well.  If Jim Lamb and the crew are listening, being able to version control the elements of the process template would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to query the command log in the collection database. *Note: it's generally recommended not to query the database directly, since the schema is not documented/supported and could change in a future release.*

```
select * from tbl_Command with (nolock) where useragent LIKE 'Team Foundation (witadmin.exe%'
```

A '**exportwitd**' command will show up as Command = '**GetMetadata**'. But that is also the same command that Visual Studio makes when you connect to TFS, so you'll need to filter on the user agent.

A '**importwitd**' command will show up as Command = '**Update**'