# How to determine who deleted a TFS work item

Tags: tfs

How can one determine who deleted a TFS work item when it is removed via the command line using ...

```
witadmin destroywi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to do this by looking in the tbl_Command table of the Collection DB.

There's no real easily accessible UI log / audit trail.

[Where are logs for witadmin actions in TFS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886943/where-are-logs-for-witadmin-actions-in-tfs-2010)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/tfsadmin/thread/e026e5fb-23b2-4d11-bb1a-b00d5bf7f59b